# Can Difference-in-Difference be used when the treatment effects get smaller with time since treatment?

Tags: econometrics, causal-inference

Recently, there is an emerging line of the study said that the traditional two-way fixed effect(TWFE) is failed in a lot of case because of the heterogeneous effects of laws over time, follow some paper [Goodman-Bacon (2019)](http://goodman-bacon.com/pdfs/ddtiming.pdf), [Chaisemartin, 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08807).

Especially, Goodman, 2019 did a great job to decompose the single post-treatment dummy. In [his note](https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-my/wp-content/uploads/sites/2318/2019/10/09023516/so_youve_been_told_dd_10_9_2019.pdf), he answered the question "**Is DD wrong**":

> Not in general. The DD research design—comparing outcomes for groups
> whose treatment status changes to groups whose treatment status does
> not change—still can be a good idea. The DD specification—estimating
> the coefficient a single post-treatment dummy—is a bad idea when your
> treatment effects vary over time (**get bigger with time since
> treatment**). In this case, just summarize your findings in a different
> way—event-study or a linear trend-break, for instance.

My question here is, if I expect and argue that the treatment effects get ***smaller*** with time since treatment, so whether DD specification now is a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a few things. First, if you expect treatment effects change over time, then you want to estimate an event-study style DD specification.

If you have a single treatment timing (all treatment starts at the same time), then an event-study will unbiasedly estimate the treatment path. If you have variation in treatment timing, you want to use a modern method, e.g. [Callaway and Sant'Anna (2020)](https://pedrohcgs.github.io/files/Callaway_SantAnna_2020.pdf), [Gardner (2021)](https://jrgcmu.github.io/2sdd_current.pdf), or [Sun and Abraham (2020)](http://economics.mit.edu/files/14964)

Comment: Is there any reference or simple explanation for "* event-study style DD specification*" ?

Comment: This is a pretty user-friendly intro guide: https://mixtape.scunning.com/difference-in-differences.html#providing-evidence-for-parallel-trends-through-event-studies-and-parallel-leads